# Logging to console works, but immediately causes TypeError

Tags: javascript

I've been working on something using `node-readability`, and I'm baffled at what's causing this error.

```
var url = req.body.url;

// Now have body, let's unfluff
read(url, function(err, data, meta) {
  console.log('title:' + data.title);
  console.log('typeof: ' + typeof(data.title));
  // Create a new article using data from readability
  var article = new Article({
    title: data.title,
    raw: data.content,
    image: data.document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['og:image'].getAttribute('content'), // Could be improved

    source: url // Should strip to just domain?
  });

  console.log(article);

  // Close article to clean up jsdom and prevent leaks
  //data.close();

  // Save article
  article.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

When run with a test url, the following is logged to console.

```
title:Gardening: Time to grow potatoes, ask the expert, and jobs for the week
typeof: string

[redacted]/controllers/temp.js:56
    console.log('title:' + data.title);
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at [redacted]/controllers/temp.js:56:32
    at Object.jsdom.env.done ([redacted]/node_modules/node-readability/src/readability.js:234:18)
    at [redacted]/node_modules/node-readability/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:270:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

So, clearly it can read the title, because it prints it. Immediately, it causes a TypeError for some unknown reason. `typeof` returns string, however logging the entire data object before anything else returns:

```
[...]
content: [Getter],
title: [Getter],
html: [Getter],
document: [Getter],
[...]
```

So clearly it is not a standard string. According to the docs however, it does not use any kind of lazy processing (such that `data.title()` would be run to process just the title, reducing load on large data sets). Attempting to do this results in a similar error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'title' of undefined
    at [redacted]/controllers/temp.js:56:22
    at Request._callback ([redacted]/node_modules/node-readability/src/readability.js:172:16)
    at self.callback ([redacted]/node_modules/node-readability/node_modules/request/request.js:123:22)
```

Comment: Just to be completely clear, line 56 of temp.js (i.e. where the error is thrown from) is the second `console.log()` call (e.g. line two of the callback passed to the `read()` function), yeah?

Comment: No, line 56 is the first `console.log` (line 1 of the callback). The `typeerror` is triggered on `console.log('title:' + data.title);`, where it literally just printed the results. In fact, it printed them, moved on and printed the next line, then typeerror'd.

Comment: Ah yeah. FWIW, `title` is a getter, not a simple property; https://github.com/luin/node-readability/blob/c25f9f254f24f787688de44169db97e0b05aa619/src/readability.js#L32-34

Comment: Can you go to `[redacted]/node_modules/node-readability/src/readability.js` and check that line 234 matches [line 234 on the github repository](https://github.com/luin/node-readability/blob/c25f9f254f24f787688de44169db97e0b05aa619/src/readability.js#L234)?

Comment: Yup, matches perfectly.

Comment: ... in that case, it means that `node-readability` is erroring, and `data` is `undefined` (this marries the TypeError of (`Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`). It would therefore seem that  `read()` is being called twice... the first is succeeding, and you're seeing correct logging, but is failing on the second attempt. Try `console.log(err)` before all your `console.log()` calls to see what gets logged.

Comment: Logging `err` is null, and its only called once.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR;

Somewhere in your callback, between `console.log('typeof: ' + typeof(data.title));` and `console.log(article);`, an error is being thrown. Wrap that part of your callback within a `try/ catch`, and log the error in the `catch` to see what it is.

## Non TL;DR;

To understand *why* this is happening, take a look at [the readability source code](https://github.com/luin/node-readability/blob/c25f9f254f24f787688de44169db97e0b05aa619/src/readability.js#L227-236);

```
try {
  var readability = new Readability(window, options);

  // add meta information to callback
  callback(null, readability, meta);
} catch (ex) {
  window.close();
  return callback(ex);
}
```

In your situation, readability is completing successfully, and [is invoking your callback, passing `null, readability, meta` as the parameters](https://github.com/luin/node-readability/blob/c25f9f254f24f787688de44169db97e0b05aa619/src/readability.js#L231). However, your callback is then causing an exception, which is being caught by the `catch` in the readability source code.

Your callback is then being [called *again* by readability](https://github.com/luin/node-readability/blob/c25f9f254f24f787688de44169db97e0b05aa619/src/readability.js#L234), but this time passing `ex` *only*. *This time* your callback tries to call `data.title,` but `data` is undefined, causing *another* exception, which *isn't* within a `try/ catch`, which causes the exception to terminate your program.

This is an oversight by the readability developer; they shouldn't be calling your callback from within the `try/catch`. It should instead look something like this;

```
var readability;

try {
  readability = new Readability(window, options);
} catch (ex) {
  window.close();
  return callback(ex);
}

callback(null, readability, meta);
```